# How to start Android Lost app on stolen Samsung S4 after pushing it through Google Play?

Tags: applications

My phone was stolen, unfortunately I dont have find my phone switched on but do have location history on. I cant locate it via Android Device Manager. I done some readimng and installed Android Lost as my email is active on the phone.

On the site Android Lost its telling me to refresh and wait for a congratulations messgae.. Ho do I remotely start the application, it's showing as installed in Google Play website????

Comment: It's probably a login at their website, Or a sms message

Comment: no its not, why make a guess when you don't know the answer!

Comment: If you can't logon or sms a startup of the gps, You either downloaded a useless application or it's just as useful as Android Device Security in this situation, You need i pre-set

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way to REMOTELY ACCESS A phone other than Background Data or SMS... I could have said you open Pokémon GO and follow your balls around in circles until you find it but i went with the logical answer !.....    All remote access programs made for Android use Background data or Auto sync to control the device.. This means logging into the website and pressing connect to device over data... The Only Working Alternative is a Secret SMS that gets recognized and deleted by the target program, This usually contains control words like Locate Me 46432 ... Locate-Device-Password ...etc...